# TypeScript Mixins and Constructor Names

Tags: javascript, typescript, mixins

I have this sample of code experimenting with mixins in TypeScript. However, it is not returning what I am expecting.

It should give me: `User ({"id":3,"name":"Lorenzo Delaurentis"})`.

Instead, I am getting: `Function ({"id":3,"name":"Lorenzo Delaurentis"})`.

The line `let Name = Class.constructor.name` should give me `User`, but it is not. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
type ClassConstructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T

function withDebug<C extends ClassConstructor<{
    getDebugValue(): object
}>>(Class: C) {
    return class extends Class {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args)
        }

        debug() {
            let Name = Class.constructor.name
            let value = this.getDebugValue()
            return `${Name} (${JSON.stringify(value)})`
        }
    }
}

class DebugUser {
    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private firstName: string,
        private lastName: string
    ) {}

    getDebugValue() {
        return {
            id: this.id,
            name: `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
        }
    }
}

let User = withDebug(DebugUser)
let user = new User(3, 'Lorenzo', "Delaurentis")
console.log(user.debug())
```

P.S. I compiled with `tsc mixins --target ES6`. Otherwise, I get an error: `error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want just `Class.name`. The `Class.constructor` is `Function`.

Comment: Thanks! That avoids returning Function as the class name. But it still isn't quite what I expect. It returns DebugUser ({"id":3,"name":"Lorenzo Delaurentis"}). I thought based on how the code was structured that it would return User ({"id":3,"name":"Lorenzo Delaurentis"}).

Comment: No, the `.name` of `DebugUser` (which you are passing as the `Class` parameter) is `"DebugUser"`, and `User` is an anonymous class that has no (an empty) name. There is nothing that has `"User"` as a name.